# PHP code is not submitting data from POST

Tags: php, html

It was working until I tried adding this statement

```
<?php echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hidden1\" value=\"$id\">" ?>
```

I was able to get the indexnum from my form before but when I added that line nothing seems to load in the fields.

Here is the full form:

```
  <form name="approveform" method="POST" action="">
    <?php echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hidden1\" value=\"$id\">" ?>
    Index Number*: <input type="text" name="IndexNum">&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="Approve" action="">
  </form>
```

Its getting late and I probably need to just go to sleep but IM SO CLOSE!!!  Here is the full code that processes the POST.

```
if($user_data['permissions'] >= 1)
{
    // If users permission is 1 or 2 they get a field for inputting the index # and a button to change the approve field from 0 to 1 may need to make a new field to record who approved it....

    //Determine if the order is already approved.  If not approved show index field and allow user to approve it with index number
    if($data2[0]['Approved'] == 1)
    {
        echo " <font color=\"green\"> Approved";
    }
    if($data2[0]['Approved'] == 0)
    {
        echo " Not Approved.  Supply an index number and click approve to authorize this order to be completed.";
        if (empty ($_POST) === false) 
        {
               $required_fields = array('IndexNum');
           foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value)
           {
             if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true)
             {
            $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
            break 1;
              }
           }
           if (isset($_POST['success']) === true && empty($_POST['success']) === true)
           {
               echo 'Index has been updated and Order is now set to Approved';
           }
           else
           {
            if (empty($errors) === true)
             {
                    $indexnum=$_POST['IndexNum'];
                $approvedby=$user_data['lname'];
                $vendorid1= $_POST['hidden1'];
                echo $indexnum;
                echo $approvedby;
                echo $vendorid1;
                    //update_approved($indexnum, $approvedby, $vendorid1);
                //header('Location: index.php');
                //exit();
            }
            else if(empty($errors) === false)
            {
                echo output_errors($errors);
            }
        }
     }
     ?>         
    <form name="approveform" method="POST" action="">
      <?php echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hidden1\" value=\"$id\">" ?>
      Index Number*: <input type="text" name="IndexNum">&nbsp;
      <input type="submit" value="Approve" action="">
    </form>

    <?php } 

}
```

Thank you all for looking into this.  I get that $id value from a previous POST.  I use it elsewhere in the code without issue.

Thank you all so much!

Comment: Also ensure the $id has some value. Just do a var_dump($id); to be sure about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
```

Also try like

```
<?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value=".$id.">' ?>
```

Comment: @HELPMEPLEASE then please mark his answer as "Accepted", he deserves some reputation.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I dont deserve a reputation.I want to help him by answering it.Thats it.. ;-)